# while and if loop code error

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The question is to Imagine a program that compresses files to 80 percent of their original size and stores them on storage media.  Before the compressed file is stored, it must be divided into blocks of 512 bytes each.  Write a program that first reads the number of blocks available on the storage media.  Then, in a loop, read the uncompressed size of the file and determine whether the compressed file will fit in the space left on the storage media.  If so, the program should compress and save the file.  It continues until it encounters a file that will exceed the available space on the media.

However, my code keeps returning integers that are incorrect....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2Q2

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

int size;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the number of blocks available");

size=keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Available number of blocks is " + size);

int filesize;


while(size!=0)

{

System.out.println("Enter the size of the file that is to be stored");

filesize=keyboard.nextInt();

filesize=filesize/512*80/100;



System.out.println("compressed file size is " + filesize);

if(filesize>size)

{

System.out.println("the number of blocks available, " + size + " is less than the required number, " + filesize);

break;

}

else
size=size-filesize;
{
System.out.println("available number of blocks is " + size);

}

}

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a new value to the variabe `size`, but only to `sizenew`. So when you finally print that there is no space available, it will print the original size.

Comment: I am sorry I am brand new at this, can you explain where the new value needs to go?

Comment: Well, in the case the file fits on to the drive, you calculate the `sizenew = size - compsize` ie. The size, after the file is written is the current available size minus the size of the file you write. Thus, in the next loop you have to compare to the new size and not the old one. So just drop the newsize variable completely and just assing the new size to the size variable, ie `size = size - compsize`; So in each iteration of the loop, the available size will be reduced accordingly

Comment: I took your advice and just changed the variable, but now my math is coming out wrong for example if I input "50" then "25000" it returns that the compressed file is 38 blocks and that there are 12 blocks left, but 25000/512*80/100 =39.06 which should come out to 40 as an int right? i have edited the code above to show my changes.

Comment: That's because of how ints work in Java. This is calculated AS follows: 25000/512 = 48.83. converting this to an int gives 48, ie it's not rounded but truncated. 48*80 = 3840. and 3840/100 = 38.4, which is the value of 38, you observe.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it seems you have very little knowledge of programming. Maybe it would be best, if you read some introductions and tutorials first to learn some basics.